# How to listen to an ObservableObject

Tags: ios, swift, observable, swiftui

Ok, so `SwiftUI` and `ObservableObject`, on iOS 13.  I have `Model` that implements `ObservableObject`:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var toggle: Bool = false

    init() {
        NSLog("Model init")
        objectWillChange.sink { void in
            NSLog("1 toggle \(self.toggle)")
        }
        $toggle.sink { v in
            NSLog("2 toggle \(self.toggle) -> \(v)")
        }
    }
}
```

and a Button that toggles `toggle`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.model.toggle.toggle()
        }, label: {Text(model.toggle ? "on" : "off")})
    }
}
```

Now, this works.  You hit the button and it toggles between "on" and "off".  (Before making `toggle` `@Published`, it did not.)  However, the logging does not work as expected.  I get two logs immediately on startup: "Model init" and "2 toggle false -> false".  Tapping the button, though apparently changing the value of `toggle`, does not cause either of the closures to execute.

When the view mutates your model, I'd expect there to be a way to be informed of the change, in case you need to e.g. update calculated values or sync to disk or something.  Perhaps `sink` is the wrong method?

How can an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` fields be notified when its fields are updated?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The latest documentation for the the return value on the [`sink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/sink(receivevalue:)) function:

`/// - Returns: A cancellable instance; used when you end assignment of the received value. Deallocation of the result will tear down the subscription stream.`

Essentially this means that sink makes a `Subscriber` but doesn't retain it. As soon as your init is done the subscribers are torn down and removed from memory. You need to keep them around by creating a strong reference like this:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var toggle: Bool = false

    var changeSink: AnyCancellable?
    var toggleSink: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        NSLog("Model init")
        changeSink = objectWillChange.sink { void in
            NSLog("1 toggle \(self.toggle)")
        }
        toggleSink = $toggle.sink { v in
            NSLog("2 toggle \(self.toggle) -> \(v)")
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't used much `Combine` but an alternative I've seen often that you might consider is just adding a `didSet` to your attribute like so:

```
    public var toggle: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("1 toggle \(self.toggle)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing!  Thanks!  I might use `didSet` sometime, but it's also good to know how to monitor everything at once with objectWillChange.  `objectDidChange` might be nice, too, but I don't think that's given to us, at least by default.

Answer (score 6):

Your ObservableObject Class **Model** is done correctly, But:

**1. ObjectWillChange should be of type ObservableObjectPublisher()**.

> That creates an objectWillChange property as an instance of
>   ObservableObjetPublisher. This comes from the Combine framework, which
>   is why you need to add import Combine to make your code compile. The
>   job of an observable object publisher is simple: whenever we want to
>   tell the world that our object has changed, we ask the publisher to do
>   it for us.

**2. the property you need to observe (Toggle) should be implemented this way:**

```
 var toggle = "" {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
```

> Second, we have a willSet property observer attached to the Toggle
>   property of Model so that we can run code whenever that
>   value changes. In our your example code, we call objectWillChange.send()
>   whenever toggle changes, which is what tells the objectWillChange
>   publisher to put out the news that our data has changed so that any
>   subscribed views can refresh.

**3. make sure your class Model conforms to ObservableObject, and the its instance is marked with *@ObservedObject***

> As Your Model class conforms to ObservableObject, you can
>   use it just like any other @ObservedObject property. So, we might use
>   it like this to watch the toggle, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.model.toggle.toggle()
        }, label: {Text($model.toggle ? "on" : "off")})
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,
reference: 
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-send-state-updates-manually-using-objectwillchange